# How can I bundle a aws ec2 windows machine with installed applications

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a ec2 windows machine with adobe after effects running. I am trying to create a template from this ec2 instance which should allow me to launch new ec2 windows instances with adobe after effects already being preinstalled. However, it looks like that is not possible. The option to "bundle instance" is greyed out. Or have I misconfigured the ec2 template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Bundle" commands are outdated.

You should simply use **Create Image** to create an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) of the existing instance. Then, you can **Launch an instance from the AMI** and it will contain an exact copy of the AMI.

See: [Creating a Custom Windows AMI - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/Creating_EBSbacked_WinAMI.html)

**Recommendation:** Run `sysprep` before creating the image. This will avoid conflicting machine IDs.

See: [Create a Standard Amazon Machine Image Using Sysprep - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ami-create-standard.html)